# Remove the "You are now attacking/defending!" message

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'd like to remove this message whenever I join a server. If that is not possible, I'd like to shorten the length it shows there for. It's very distracting and makes it harder to play while it's up.

I'm talking about this message:

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, there should be a 'turn off tutorials' or tooltips, or something like that in the options

Comment: @eyeofthehawks Do you know what tab it's under? The closest thing I see is in options->multiplayer->advanced and says `Show pop-up alerts while in-game (eg. trade requests)`. However this does not turn the message off.

Comment: I thought this message goes away automatically after playing the map X times, though maybe I'm just tuning it out by now.

Comment: Nah, I've played hundreds of hours of TF2.

Comment: @Chipperyman No, it should definitely be going away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to bind a key to the following command:

> record demo; stop

What this will do is start creating a video demo named "demo", then stop recording.  By recording a demo and stopping, you will refresh your HUD and elements on screen.  I have this binded to my backspace key so if issues occur during a game, you can press Backspace, wait a few seconds, then your screen should be cleared of that message.

Comment: Will this override the previous demo?

Comment: @Chipperyman It depends on what you named your previous demo.  For example, if you're in the middle of recording a demo, then this isn't a very good solution.  If you just play the game without recording anything, then yes, since you are writing to a file named 'demo' and stopping it instantly, nothing is saved to the demo and the program will continually use the "same" demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

`cl_showhelp 0`

The [Valve Developer's Wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/List_of_TF2_console_commands_and_variables) says it disables "on-screen help" and I found a few forum threads giving this answer but nothing has been conclusive.